# Converting list of strings to rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     mAID  MAID  PIDs
0    A     D     [YY, ZZ]
1    B     E     [XY]
2    A     E     [YY, XX]
3    A     F     [YY, XX, ZZ]
```

I want to convert it to such:

```
 mAID  MAID  PIDs
 A     D     YY
 A     D     ZZ
 B     E     XY
 A     E     YY
 A     E     XX 
 A     F     YY
 A     F     XX
 A     F     ZZ
```

Thank you.

Comment: There are multiple method , you can pick and choice

Comment: try `pd.DataFrame(df.PIDs.str.replace('\[|\]', '').str.split(',').tolist(), index=[df.mAID, df.MAID]).stack().reset_index()`